# Take screenshot of terminal

Tags: gnome, graphics, gnome-terminal, command-line, productivity

I'm Using Gnome2.

I have on My first workspace two terminals open (gnome-terminal).

I want a screenshot of the whole terminal1 window.

I don't want set up the bounding box of the screenshot with my mouse, or pointing with it that window.

How I can do that from the console on terminal2 ?

Comment: There is a shortcut for taking a screenshot of the active window: Alt+Print

Comment: He is asking for a screenshot of the terminal without borders, menus and the such. Alt-Print will include borders, menus, etc of the selected window. For other types of screenshots (full screen, specific area, full selected windows) search here: http://askubuntu.com/search?q=screenshot

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `gnome-panel-screenshot` command in a terminal (of course, a different one), by dropping the `--window` (or `-w`) parameter, which will allow you to grab a window instead of the entire screen.

The command should look like:

```
gnome-panel-screenshot --window --delay=10
```

or

```
gnome-panel-screenshot -w -d 10
```

Both the `--delay=10` and the `-d 10` parameters will give you 10 seconds in order to choose the appropriate window of which you wish a screenshot. Change this value in order to adjust it to your needs.

If you wish a screenshot of the current terminal window simply drop the `gnome-panel-screenshot -window` or `gnome-panel-screenshot -w` without any other parameters, for the whole screen drop no parameters at all.

For a guided screenshot grabbing simply drop the `gnome-panel-screenshot -i` command in a terminal which will produce this window:

[image: gnome-panel-screenshot GUI]

BTW: You don't need to drop this last one in a terminal, simply hit the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> keys and enter it in the "Run application" dialog window. After which you can choose whatever options that better fits your needs for screen-shooting.

[image: Run Application Dialog Window]

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways to grab the terminal without any borders and menus like for example: Say you have 2 Terminal opens, one you renamed to **Terminal R2D2** and the other to **Terminal C3PO** if you wanted a screenshot for each you would go to each terminal and run the command `import` with the following data:

Inside any Terminal:
`import -windows "Terminal R2D2" R2D2Test.jpg`

Inside any Terminal:
`import -windows "Terminal C3PO" C3POTest.jpg`

This will capture your terminal window with the Title you mention. Noticed you can capture any window. In this case is only the terminal windows or any amount of terminal windows.

You need to specify a title for your terminal by going in the terminal menu to Terminal -> Title

NOTE - The **MenuBar** will show in the screenshots if you do not disable it from the Menu. Go to View -> Show MenuBar to disable it. To enable just right click the Terminal and select Show MenuBar.

I did not mention Shutter, Ksnapshot or the commong ALT+PrtScrn options since you want a specific terminal way that does not capture borders or mouse pointers.

Comment: Very nice. N.b.: It will ignore transparency and all window decorations, but you can specify to include the border if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using scrot

```
sudo apt-get install scrot
scrot -s -b other-terminal-window.png
```

You still need to click on the other terminal window though.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut key to capture a window is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd>. The shortcut key to capture the whole desktop is <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>. You could also try a tool for taking screenshots like `Shutter`